# Applying lambda to variable number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, data-science

I am trying to implement something in Python and I am stuck.

I have 2 dataframes, `df1` and `df2`. I have to create a new column in `df1` using the following logic.

```
col_list = ['colA', 'colB', 'colC']
df1['label_id'] = df1[['colA', 'colB', 'colC']].apply(
            lambda x: df2[x[0], x[1], x[2]], axis=1)
```

Here, `x[0]` corresponds to `colA`, `x[1]` corresponds to `colB`, `x[2]` corresponds to `colC`. As you can see, this is hardcoding. The number and names of columns in `col_list` will vary, and accordingly I should have `x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]`... and so on.

So how do I make this configurable in implementation?

Appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it looks like a good question, but i am not sure that i understand the question clearly enough to answer it....  the code provided is not sufficiently clear:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It looks like you want to do a `merge`...

Comment: Can you share an example?

Comment: 1) Does this part of your code work: `d2[x[0], x[1], ...]`? It looks a bit confusing. 2) Why not to use `'df2[x]`?

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for replying. Yes, I will share an example of input and output. @Vitalizzare Yes, that part works.